# What exactly is Block Rendering?

Tags: javascript, html

[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RRnyChxijA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RRnyChxijA#t=20m43s)

@20:43 min of the video talks about Block Rendering - "Directly replace innerHtml with a huge string instead of multiple DOM append operations"

What does that exactly mean? Does it mean that the code are some how in blocks of strings of html already instead of progressively manipulating the DOM tree?

If so does anyone have an example of this? Using javascript/html/css without php?

Does he mean that he has hidden divs and then displays them later?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is talking about the two ways of replacing content

1. append DOM elements, etc

   ```
   var div = document.getElementById('something').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
   ```
2. replace `innerHTML` with a serialised list of HTML elements

   ```
   var div = document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = '<div></div>'
   ```

Comment: Thank you, upon your explanation and getting a better view on this, I've looked up innerHTML and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694233/create-append-node-vs-innerhtml which help alot.

Answer (score 2):

It just means replacing a large chunk of the DOM in one go instead of in multiple pieces. It means the browser only has to redraw the page once.

You can get the same effect by using multiple DOM append operations on an element not connected to the DOM and *then* appending that one element.